# what is the mean difference between Nest and redis-namespace gems when we use redis with rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, key-value-store

There is two popular gem for adding namespace to redis : **redis-namespace** and **Nest**, if i really understand we need namespace when we use the same instance server of redis with different projects, if i'm right this means : if i have project-1 and project-2 and each of these projects use my local redis storage, then perhaps the two projects have a *users* key which represente users of my app, so to prevent the conflict i need to namespace **users key** with something like the name of project :

for project-1 :

```
project-1:users
```

for project-1

```
project-2:users
```

if my above understand is not wrong, we can use `redis-namespace gem` to solve this like this :

```
r = Redis::Namespace.new(:project-1, :redis => @r)
r['users']['joe']['email'] = 'joe@example.com'
```

and for the second project (project-2) just need to change project-1 to project-2 when instantiate new Redis::Namespace  :

```
 r = Redis::Namespace.new(:project-2, :redis => @r)
 r['users']['joe']['email'] = 'joe@example.com'
```

**please tell me if i'm not wrong in all this above explanation !**

we can now continue with Nest :

from [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/nest/1.1.2/frames) we have this example :

> Nest helps you generate keys by providing chainable namespaces that are already connected to Redis:

```
>> event = Nest.new("event")
>> event[3][:attendees].sadd("Albert")
>> event[3][:attendees].smembers
=> ["Albert"]
```

but here i'm not sure if Nest help us to do the same thing as redis-namespace or help us just to generate a chainable keys  ???

what is exactly the difference between redis-namespace and Nest ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Nest.

You can accomplish the same with both libraries, and I think the main differentiator between those tools is their internal complexity. While Nest only helps you in representing structure with flat keys, Redis::Namespace has a translation table for every command and it's thus more fragile and CPU intensive.

Take a look at the source code of both tools to see what I mean:

https://github.com/soveran/nest/blob/master/lib/nest.rb

https://github.com/resque/redis-namespace/blob/master/lib/redis/namespace.rb

That said, the right solution to the problem you described is to have separate Redis instances for different projects. Consider that the keyspace is only one aspect to take into account (which could be also solved easily with the different DBs provided by Redis). The other aspects (persistence strategy, connection and memory limits, key evictions, etc.) are usually fine tuned depending on the nature of the project.

Another important fact is that Redis is single threaded, and many applications are using it you are subject to sharing the same core for all the requests. With that in mind, having different Redis instances helps you parallelize work.

Comment: Hi soveran, thank you for explanation, I looked at the source code very quickly, if i understand redis-namespace do lot of test (case) switch COMMANDS table, i see also that its code source is bigger which means a lot of processing, so i can understand that Nest is more efficient, I have a note : i find that expliquations on how to use Nest are not enough, we need also to know more details of its advantage and why it should be used,I googled a long time but I have not found a simple tutorial that explains these points

Comment: i have a question please : i watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dH6VYRMRQFw his author explains redis with rails and he use Nest lib, at 10:27m he shows us that he extend Nest to use key.to_param instead of key.to_s in the initialize method, what is the difference here ?

Answer (score 0):

You know http://redis.io/commands/select for he parallel running of multiple databases on one server? Here you don't have a key conflict and the databases are separated. Only if you access to keys from all databases at once it's not possible.