# A method definition begins with brackets, can't understand its usefulness

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I see a method's definition like this:

```
def [](param)
   # do stuff
end
```

What does this method declaration mean? How does it work?  When to use it? And how to call this kinds of method with an instance object?

Comment: `[]` are called brackets. The term "hook" as a completely different meaning in programming. You should be careful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the method's name, `[]`. You might already know `Array#[]` or `Hash#[]`. In your classes you can define such method too. What it will do - it's up to you.

```
class Foo
  def [](param)
    # body
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f[:some_value]
```

Comment: here :some_value is the param in my declaration ?

Comment: Yes, it'll be available as `param` in the method body

Comment: can you look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559961/what-is-the-mean-difference-between-nest-and-redis-namespace-gems-when-we-use-re

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused. Did you mean "Its method's name" or "It's a/the method's name"?

Comment: @Jefffrey: yeah, missed an article there. You see, english is my second language :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, Oh, don't worry. It happens. And english is my second language too. :)

Answer (score 2):

It means the method is named "`[]`". You call it like any other method:

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
a.[](1)    # => 'bar'
```

Additionally, for methods with this name, you can also call them like

```
a[1]       # => 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this [**Array#[]**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) ? It will give you some idea about that..

```
   [1,2].[](1) # => 2
         |  |
--------->  <---------
method name  argument
```